# Sending 2 or more PDF via Email out of Core Data

Tags: ios, email, pdf, core-data

I have many PDFs in Core Data. How can I attach one ore more PDFs out of core data to an eMail?
Is it better to merge the PDFs to one?

Best regards
Andreas

Comment: I don't see how Core Data is important to this question.

Answer (score 0):

The `MFMailComposeViewController` class has a method called `addAttachmentData:mimeType:fileName:` that attaches binary objects (like PDFs) to emails. Get your PDFs and attach them. Whether to merge PDFs depends on what you're doing and whether it makes sense for your documents and your users.

Core Data has nothing to do with this-- As long as you have an `NSData`, you can attach it. It doesn't matter where it came from.

Comment: Oh, thank you so much. So I have to call addAttachmentData:mimeType:fileName: for each PDF, I think. Perfect!